# How to include a template for a static xml block

Tags: layout, magento-2.1, xml

Can I include a template into the xml for designing a specific static block? This would enable a non technical user to create a static block in the admin, without having to add a   into the html part of the admin/cms editor? So in the template there would just be the html markup for the  part ? Is that possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>         
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name="cms.block1" before="-" class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" cacheable="true">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms_block_1</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

      <block name="cms.block2" after="cms.block1" class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" cacheable="true">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms_block_2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is my xml which handles the static blocks on the homepage. Now I added the  manually into the static blocks.

So how to call a .phtml file? And how would that file look like?

Can I just have:

```
<div class=""></div> in that file or 
do i need something like: <div class="">cms_block_1</div> ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll create a template file in the concerned Module in your custom theme. Let's say you want to add a CMS block **cms_block_1** to home page you'll create a template `mytemplate.phtml` under `<theme>/Magento_CMS/templates` directory with following:

```
<div class="my-class">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('cms_block_1')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

Now in `<theme>/Magento_CMS/layout/cms_index_index.xml` file add

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my.block1" template="Magento_Cms::mytemplate.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Tried that and its giving me this output in the frontend:
`code  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('cms_block_1')->toHtml();  `

Comment: PHP tags were missing, see my edit above!

Comment: I already added them myself. But still getting the output? Will try again and remove all cached files before (not only the pub/static).

Comment: Ok it works. Do I need to have a separate template for every cms-block or can I combine lets say block_1 block_2 into that one file? To get it working with the xml as in my question above? 

So It will have: 

`code <div class="my-class">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('cms_block_1')->toHtml(); ?>
</div> `

and

`code <div class="my-other_class">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('cms_block_2')->toHtml(); ?>
</div> `

Comment: Awesome, you can add as many cms blocks as you need and your code seems to be correct :)

Comment: Ok nice solution :)